# Use greek with JSON

Tags: jquery, json

This is a JSON I'm writing and use it with JQuery.

```
bookData.webSites = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "ΤΟΥΡΙΣΤΙΚΗ ΑΝΑΠΤΥΞΗ",
        image: 'images/books/min.png',
        site: 'http://delicious.com/',
        author: "",
        pages: '',
        isbn: '',
        price: '',
        type: 'book'
    }];
```

It works perfect until I'm trying to use a long Greek text with it, then It goes really wrong. I had some problems with the author tag but it all went well when I used `""` instead of `''`. In a long Greek text we use `"` and `'` while writing and I apparently want to use greek for the description. Any way for that to became posible.

Thanks beforehand for everyones help from this AWESOME community!

Comment: How do things go "really wrong"? And what is the exact string that makes it go wrong? Please try to post the actual text that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing an escape character (`'\'`) before each instance of `"` or `'`.

JavaScript JSON libraries should handle this for you. Example - http://www.json.org/js.html: see `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: When I experimented a bit more I found out that that wasn't the big deal after all. As I copy & pasted the text there where EOL characters or something. So after I got rid of those it worked like a charm again. Thanks for the help thought. After reading through it carefully I attain a better understudying of json. That's definitely not a waste of time.